# Updating google map markers without reloading map and blinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a project where I should create a web page that shows Google map with the markers at the specified GPS coordinates. 
The project is organized in the following way. At the server side, I have the php script that accepts HTTP request from a GPS device, receives and stores GPS coordinates in the corresponding .txt file. The php file also includes javascript/jquery code that reads the .txt file with the GPS coordinates, create new instance of Google map and put the markers on map for the user that make request in a web browser. As I am electronic hardware engineer, this is pretty new for me. The code I found reloads the map on every 5 second, but that makes the map flashing/blinking for a while on each reload. Also, if I change the zooming manually in the browser, it resets to default on each map reload. Is there any way to avoid map blinking, and update markers smoothly. In the following is the snippet of the javascript/jquery code I have.

```
function initialize()
    {
        mapProp = {
          center:myCenter,
          zoom:17,
          mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
        setInterval('mark()',5000);
    }

    function mark()
    {
            map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        var file = "gps.txt";
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
                $.get(file, function(txt) { 
            var lines = txt.split("\n");

            for (var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
                console.log(lines[i]);
                var words=lines[i].split(",");
                if ((words[0]!="")&&(words[1]!=""))
                {
                    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                          position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),
                          });
                    marker.setMap(map);
                    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()).title(entry.getKey()));
                }
            }
            lastLength = lines.length;
            marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        });

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: There is a whole lot to fix in there. Both in code and in logic. What's the format of `gps.txt` ? Are coordinates appended to it or is it overwritten entirely ?

Comment: Coordinates are append to it.

Comment: And it's just a list of "long,lat" ?

Comment: It includes some additional parameters, like the number of satellites, time... All the parameters are comma separated. When fresh list of parameters arrive, it is appended at the new line in a .txt file.

Comment: So we can identify each set of coordinates by line number ?

Comment: Yes, each line corresponds to one coordinate .

Comment: I am trying to change markers without reload map. But everytime map is reload along with markers. Can you please have a look into the code and please help me point the issue ... here is the link https://gist.github.com/karamjeetmultani/2f973d32b701948530f2f84fcb73ee2c

Answer (score 1):

### What is going on

You keep recreating the map on every update rather than creating it once and add new markers to it.

### Fixed code, with comments:

```
function initialize() {

   // map starting point
   var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

   // coordinates file
   var file = "gps.txt";

   // init and keep a reference to last line of coordinates
   var lastLength = 0;

   // init and keep reference to last set marker
   var marker;

   // map options
   var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:17,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };

   // create map
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

   // execute once
   mark();

   // set update
   setInterval(mark, 5000);

   // this runs on schedule to add new markers
   function mark() {

      $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});

      $.get(file, function(txt) {

         var lines = txt.split("\n");

         // disable animation on last marker from previous update
         if(marker) {
            marker.setAnimation(null);
         }

         // start from last line + 1 from previous update
         for(var i=lastLength; i<lines.length; ++i) {

            // some debug
            //console.log(lastLength);
            //console.log(lines[i]);

            var words=lines[i].split(",");

            if(words[0] != "" && words[1] != "") {

               // new marker
               marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]),
               });

               // put marker on map
               marker.setMap(map);

               // center on marker
               map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1]));

               // I don't know the api enough to fix this part although it seems to work without it
               //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()).title(entry.getKey()));
            }
         }

         // update list starting position
         lastLength = lines.length;

         //set animation on current last marker
         marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
      }, 'text'); // added datatype:text
   }
}

// init
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: I think this solved problem particularly. There is no map blinking, but new GPS coordinates are not added to the map automatically. It requires manually reloading the page to display new markers (new coordinates lines from txt file added in meanwhile).

Comment: Strange, it works fine on my end when I update `gps.txt`. Any particular javascript errors ?

Comment: I got it! I downloaded newer version of jquery. Now it works. Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: I am trying to change markers without reload map. But everytime map is reload along with markers. Can you please have a look into the code and please help me point the issue ... here is the link https://gist.github.com/karamjeetmultani/2f973d32b701948530f2f84fcb73ee2c

Answer (score 0):

remove this line to get rid of bouncing issue.

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

While you are plotting the markers hold them in an array

```
marker[j]=new google.maps.Marker({position:new google.maps.LatLng(words[0],words[1])});
```

and later only add new ones to the map or remove all old one by

```
marker[j].setMap(null);
```

and then plot all markers afresh.

Comment: I am trying to change markers without reload map. But everytime map is reload along with markers. Can you please have a look into the code and please help me point the issue ... here is the link https://gist.github.com/karamjeetmultani/2f973d32b701948530f2f84fcb73ee2c